# How to access the dependency versions in a Create-React-App

Tags: create-react-app, package.json

In a create-react-app i would like to access some properties of the package.json and show those to the user in the browser. Like the version of the app and the version of some of the dependencies specified in the package.json.

How would I access those properties, without importing and exposing the whole package.json to the client?

Comment: did my answer solve the question for you? Just following up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing npm run build on the create-react-app provides a production bundle in the ./build directory.

Solution 1:
The way it works it does not expose the rest of the package.json content to the production bundle when making a destructured import. (E.g. previous answer from [Devchris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996795/2361500))

```
import { dependencies } from './package.json';
```

Solution 2:
By extending the npm scripts it is possible to read and expose the package.json into the node environment and read it from there at build time (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

```
process.env.REACT_APP_DEPENDENCIES
```

Note: The variable must start with 'REACT_APP_'

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
import { version, dependencies } from './package.json';
```

this will give you all dependencies and the version of your `package.json` in your js code. Keep in mind that your path to the `package.json` file might be different.